# Workaround for kendo grid column resize bug in combination with IE

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I think I have found a bug in the kendoui grid when column resizing is enabled (version 2013.1.319). All columns but one disappear when resizing.

I'm testing this in IE9 and IE8. Chrome does not have the bug (maybe other browser also don't)

Here is a jsbin that displays the problem:[demo](http://jsbin.com/uxomec/1/edit)

Has anyone has a workaround for this bug?

Comment: found a possible duplicate of this problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579682/kendo-grid-resize-shrinks-all-the-columns-in-ie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the column a width, we using the same Kendo build and it works in IE, but we have a width on every column :

```
    columns: [
            {
                title: "one", width: "50px"
            },
```

Comment: Ended up doing this.. but I don't like it.

Comment: I can see why you don't like it and I totally agree, on the other hand what else to expect from IE. Did you report it to Kendo people ? (Some simple behind the scenes minWidth could sort it out )

Comment: @Vojtiik i did what you said but still not able to resize my column width :( any other workaround

Answer (score 0):

I Just did this

```
.k-grid td {
        max-width: 200px;
    }
```

after javascript initialized grid